# How to notify mail group owners when a new member added to mail group?

Tags: active-directory, exchange

Is there a way to inform mail group owners when a new user added to their business unit's mail group? For example in Active Directory there is a Finance distribution list owned by CFO's assistant. I'm looking for a way to inform assistant when a user added to their mail group. Btw I'm not looking for a solution not just one group. I mean all mail group owners should be notified in Active Directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exchange Scripting Agent (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2014/06/24/exchange-scripting-agent-the-power-of-script/).

Write your script to run when 'Add-DistributionGroupMember' executed. Owner can be determined by 'ManagedBy' attribute of that distribution group.

Comment: Hi Vadim,

Thank you so much for your reply. Is it possible you to share a sample script for an example distribution list for me to understand logic?